# github add SSH key - not able to add sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256

Tags: github, ssh, key, ecdsa

GitHub - new SSH key - add SSH key
-> Key field shows "`Begins with ... 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256'...`" but NOT "`Begins with 'sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256'...`".

-> not able to add my key beginning with 'sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256'
-> error: `Key is invalid. You must supply a key in OpenSSH public key format`

How am I able to add my SSH key using HSK in format sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 ?
And if not yet possible, when will the support for this be added?

Comment: If the type of your key is actually `sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com`, then that's supported.  I see it on GitHub.  Are you using github.com or a GittHub Enterprise Server instance, and if the latter, what version?

Comment: I use the web interface of my company github.<companyname>.com/... Where can I see a version of it?

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason why the key is not accepted is for a GHE (GitHub Enterprise) older than [3.2 (Sept. 2021)](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.2/admin/release-notes#3.2.0)

3.2 includes [SSH authentication with security keys](https://docs.github.com/enterprise-server@3.2/admin/release-notes#ssh-authentication-with-security-keys)

> SSH authentication using a FIDO2 security key is now supported when you add a `sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com` or `sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com` SSH key to your account.
>
> SSH security keys store secret key material on a separate hardware device that requires verification, such as a tap, to operate.

Comment: I use the web interface of my company github.<companyname>.com/... Where can I see a version of it?

Comment: @trout At the bottom of the page, or using a REST API endpoint, [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65352594/6309.

Comment: we use GitHub Enterprise Server 3.1.23
thank you so much for the hint